# Reference Request

Tags: mathtools

I want to know and read about Latex mathematics . I thought to know and understand about Latex mathematics by reading some books relating to Latex . I  failed to find out exact and suitable books . This is why , I request some fundamental books which will be helpful to me .
I am waiting for any suggestion or advice from the community .
Thanks a lots .

Comment: Please specify what you mean by latex mathematics and remove the spaces before the punctuation.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about typesetting mathematics using LaTeX, then I strongly recommend George Grätzer's book *More Math into LaTeX*, 5th edition, Springer 2016.